# Angular : Right project structure for an app with admin backend

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I'm just done reading the book "ng-book : The complete book on Angular 6".

I am currently having a simple question which I couldn't find a proper answer.

I would like to build an application like so :

MainLayout : Base layout for all main website pages. Beautiful header, footer, etc.
AdminLayout : Base layout all admin pages. Another header with a left sidebar.

http://my-app.com : Application with multiple routes. All routes shares the same base layout (MainLayout)

http:///my-app.com/admin : Same application, same backend, however it uses a different layout than the main website (AdminLayout), but all child routes of /admin shares the same layout (AdminLayout).

What I though I could do :

- app

  - admin

    - admin.module.ts (define admin routes)
    - admin.component.ts (and html has a router-outlet)
  - main

    - main.module.ts (defines main routes)
    - main.component.ts (and html has a router-outlet)
  - app.module.ts (with router/empty route)
  - app-routing.component.ts (with router-outlet)

Is it the right way of doing it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is perfect. There are a few other things that I'd like to add though.

Make sure that all the routes, that you've said are there in the main layout, as well as the admin layout, are lazily loaded.

So ideally, for each route that you're creating, you'll have to create a module and a routing module. These routes and the components and the sub-components that will be rendered as a part of these main components(that you've specified in the route config) will reside in the module folders.

If there are a few components that you think will be reused throughout the whole application, consider adding a `SharedModule` and `export`ing them as a part of that.

Also, I feel since the header and footer are single-use components, you should consider moving them to a `CoreModule` and then importing the `CoreModule` in your `AppModule`.

All these recommendations are as per the [**Angular Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) that you might want to read through, thoroughly as well.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply ! May I ask you why it is better to create a new module and a new routing module for each route ? Let's say I want to see news which is part of the app/main/news, why shouldn't I just declare its route in main.module.ts ? Also, if main and admin are using different head/footer, why is it better to extract them in a CoreModule and import it in the root module (AppModule) ? Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: To answer your first question, it's better to lazily load every single route that you can lazy load in an Angular App. `app/main/news` looks like a module that you can lazily load. So why not. And to lazily load a module, there's a convention to create a routing module for the lazily loaded module and the provide a part to the lazily loaded module as the value of the `loadChildren` property.

Comment: To answer your second question, I was assuming that the header and footer are going to be the same for both main and admin. If that's not really the case, that please ignore the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say there is a route /admin/users which is a list of users, `app/admin/admin-routing.module` would be lazy loaded by `app/app-routing.module` and `app/admin/admin-routing.module` would lazy load `app/admin/users/users.module.ts` which defines `app/admin/users/user-list/user-list.component` Did I understand right ? Thank you

Comment: Exactly. `AppRoutingModule` would lazy load `AdminModule` and `AdminRoutingModule` would lazy load `UsersModule`.

Comment: Thank you :) ! I would have one more question : what if I have 2 different users list. I understand that if I need to share it, I would move under a SharedModule. However, if they need to be 2 different components : `app/admin/users/user-list` and `app/main/users/user-list` will they conflict if they have the same name or same tag name ? If yes, does it mean one should be called AdminUserList ?  Should my tag name in admin folder be `admin-user-list` instead of `app-user-list` ? Thanks again

Comment: Well, if the component's look and feel is the same, I believe they should be in the `SharedModule`. But if that's not the case, they should be in their respective modules. And if that's the case, their selector names can't be same. If they're same, you're going to get an error saying **Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.**

Comment: Thank you for clarifying everything ! Very appreciated ! :)